# How can I control the order of results? Lucene range queries in Cloudant

Tags: lucene, cloudant

I've got a simple index which outputs a "score" from 1000 to 12000 in increments of 1000. I want to get a range of results from a lo- to high -score, for example;

```
q=score:[1000 TO 3000]
```

However, this always returns a list of matches starting at 3000 and depending on the limit (and number of matches) it might never return any 1000 matches, even though they exist. I've tried to use sort:+- and grouping but nothing seems to have any impact on the returned result.

So; how can the order of results returned be controlled?

What I ideally want is a selection of matches from the range but I *assume* this isn't possible, given that the query just starts filling the results in from the top?

For reference the index looks like this;

```
function(doc) {
    var score = doc.score;
    index("score", score, {
        "store": "yes"
    });
...
```

Comment: I don't *think* I can use boost btw; the only thing that makes one index higher value than another is the score, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on this so posting an answer here:

Based on the cloudant doc on lucene queries, there isn't a way to sort results of a query. The sort options given there are for grouping. And even for grouped results I never saw sort work. In any case it is supposed to sort the sequence of the groups themselves. Not the data within.

Answer (score 0):

@pal2ie you are correct, and Cloudant has come back to me confirming it. It does make sense, in some way, but I was hoping I could at least control the direction (lo->hi, hi->lo). The solution I have implemented to get a better distribution across the range is to not use range queries but instead;

1. create a distribution of the number of desired results for each score in the range (a simple, discrete, Gaussian for example)
2. execute individual queries for each score in the range with limit set to the number of desired results for that score
3. execute step 2 from min to max, filling up the result

It's not the most effective since it means multiple round-trips to the server but at least it gives me full control over the distribution in the range